# Listing page attachments in Screwturn

Tags: screwturn

Does anyone know of a way to display a list of page attachments in the body of the page using Screwturn? I am using 3.0.4.560 and have searched for plugs but can not find it.

All I want is to enter a bit of wiki markup and a list of all page attachments are shown in a table ready for the user to download them.

I am pretty sure its possible, as each page already has a drop down menu with this information, I just want to display in the actual page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way I've found is not to use page attachments, but to use file links instead:

1. Go to `http://yourwikiname.com/Upload.aspx`
2. Use the **Create New Directory** section to create a folder for your files (if you want)
3. Navigate to the directory you want to put the files in.
4. In the **Upload Files** section, upload each of your files one-by-one.
5. Return to the wiki and edit the page you want the links on.
6. There's a file link toolbar button (between the blue page link button and the globe button) that you can click to add a file link.

While this is slightly more complex than attaching to a page, this method keeps your files in one central location and allows you to link to a file from any number of pages.  I've found that this is easier to manage than attaching files to individual pages.

Comment: I wanted an automatic method, a bit like adding a table of contents, it would list a table of attachments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the FileListFormatter plugin?

Find details and download here [FileListFormatter plugin](http://www.screwturn.eu/Customize.FileListFormatter.ashx).

Comment: I had tried this but couldn't get it to work for page attachments.